# Anaglyph 3D in Ubuntu

Tags: vlc, 3d

How to watch Anaglyph 3D in Ubuntu 18.04 budgie?

VLC's Anaglyph 3D setting is not working. Even ticking the advanced setting is no use.

Comment: Try `smplayer` application.

Comment: wow thanks ,it's almost looks like MPC home nice and simple and its working properly.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer below by clicking the "answer your own question" button to help future readers. Perhaps include the step(s) required to install SMPlayer and how to use the application to view 3D videos. It's absolutely fine to answer your own questions here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download SMPlayer from you default Software Center.[Software Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMlD.png)

After installation completed open it[SMPlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy5HI.png)

my smplayer looks different because i change theme(it's in option => preference => interface ).
then open any 3d video in it,then click on video option you will get an option called "Stereo 3D filter" click on it [Stereo 3D filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8icx.png)
and select your desired option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `bino`.

Run the following commands to install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bino
```